# How to remove 'nan' values in a list of string values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list, made of values from various rows, those values have to be converted into strings. The problem is when a row is empty there is a value called 'nan' displayed, which I would like to remove.

**My code :**

```
import pandas as pd

test = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
x = str(row['Date']) + ' | ' + str(row['Time'])
test.append(x)

print(test)
```

**I tried multiple things** :

```
import numpy as np

list_clean = test[np.logical_not(np.isnan(test))]
print(res_backend_nan)
```

Which says

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

I tried :

```
import math
from numpy import nan

list_clean = [item for item in test if not(math.isnan(item) == False)]
```

And it says :

> TypeError: must be real number, not P

I tried :

```
list_clean = [item for item in list if not(pd.isnull(item) == True)]
```

The result is the list is still displayed with nan values :

> 06/07/35 | nan

Some help would be very welcome please, thank you.

Comment: Why not use df.dropna() just before this code?

Comment: It didn't remove them :/

Comment: Then do check if its really a missing value like np.nan or just a string 'nan'

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_nan(row):
    return [str(x) for x in row if not pd.isnull(x)]
```

Comment: Like this ? It didn't change anything :/ : import pandas as pd

test = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
remove_nan(row)
x = str(row['Date']) + ' | ' + str(row['Time'])
test.append(x)

print(test)